# How to consume RESTFULFatSecret Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hey I'm looking for some tutorials on how to consume an external Web API in ASP.NET MVC  or if someone could explain briefly on how to go about it,specifically the https://platform.fatsecret.com/api/

Comment: Depends on how you want to consume it. You can deserialize a Web API with `Newtonsoft` in .NET, or you can make an ajax call in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki) . It makes it very easy to consume an external API in your .NET application, since you can control how the API-response (JSON or XML) is deserialized to your model classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the websites REST API Documentation on everything you need to include in your requests to their server. Here is an example of a method https://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiref&method=food.get

It breaks it down into what is required to be in your request and what you are to expect to see returned.

As for actual code, you have a few options. You can refer to [Microsoft Docs](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) in order to learn how to actually craft, send and receive requests to a REST API. The example shown uses the `asp.net client` Nuget package. It provides an object which allows you to easily create and receive requests.

Personaly, I like to practice with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) for Chrome first. It allows you to easily create and receive REST data and even has an option to create template code from your request into multiple languages!